# Add property to an array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of objects :

```
parsedObjs = [


    {
     BusinessName: 'Exmaple1...',
     Employeeid: 1234664,
     Rank: 3,
     PublishDate: 2019-08-09T21:00:00.000Z
    },
    {
     BusinessName: 'Exmaple2....',
     Employeeid: 1234666,
     Rank: 4,
     PublishDate: 2019-08-09T21:00:00.000Z
    },

    ... more

]
```

and a property that I want to add to each object :

```
const addThis = {supplier: req.supplier.id}
```

I've tried to use the spread operator :

```
   const spreadedItems = [
            ...parsedObjs,
            addThis 
          ];
```

But it doesn't do the trick.

How can we add a property to an array of objects ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to add that property to each object in the array?

To do so, you'll have to iterate it and change each item. The `.map()` method is your friend there:

```js
parsedObjs.map(item => ({...item, supplier: req.supplier.id}));
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

To add property to each element you need to loop over the array, you can use `map`

```js
let parsedObjs = [{BusinessName: 'Exmaple1...',Employeeid: 1234664,Rank: 3,PublishDate: '019 - 08 - 09 T21: 00: 00.000 Z2'},{BusinessName: 'Exmaple2....',Employeeid: 1234666,Rank: 4,PublishDate: '2019 - 08 - 09 T21: 00: 00.000 Z'},]
const addThis = {supplier: 'some id'}

const spreadedItems = parsedObjs.map(current => ({ ...current,
  ...addThis
}))

console.log(spreadedItems)
```